# How to log metrics to Azure ML Metrics Tab

Tags: python, azure-machine-learning-service, mlflow

I have the following train.py file

```
import argparse
import os
import numpy as np
import glob
# import joblib
import mlflow
import logging
import azureml.core
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd 

from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from azureml.core import Workspace, Dataset
from azureml.core.experiment import Experiment
from azureml.core.workspace import Workspace
from azureml.core.dataset import Dataset
from azureml.train.automl import AutoMLConfig
from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelEncoder,OneHotEncoder
import lightgbm as lgb
from sklearn.datasets import load_boston
from sklearn.metrics import mean_squared_error
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from pandas import DataFrame
from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelEncoder,OneHotEncoder
from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression


# let user feed in 2 parameters, the dataset to mount or download,
# and the regularization rate of the logistic regression model
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument(
    "--tablename", type=str, dest="tablename", help="Table name"
)
args = parser.parse_args()

tablename = args.tablename


subscription_id = ''
resource_group = 'mlplayground'
workspace_name = 'mlplayground'

workspace = Workspace(subscription_id, resource_group, workspace_name)

dataset = Dataset.get_by_name(workspace, name=tablename)
data = dataset.to_pandas_dataframe()

# use mlflow autologging
mlflow.autolog()

data.drop(['postal_code','Column1','province','region','lattitude','longitude'], axis=1, inplace=True)
one_hot_state_of_the_building=pd.get_dummies(data.state_of_the_building) 
one_hot_city = pd.get_dummies(data.city_name, prefix='city')

#removing categorical features 
data.drop(['city_name','state_of_the_building'],axis=1,inplace=True)  

#Merging one hot encoded features with our dataset 'data' 
data=pd.concat([data,one_hot_city,one_hot_state_of_the_building,],axis=1) 

data['pricepersqm'] = data.price / data.house_area

x=data.drop('price',axis=1) 
y=data.price 

X_df = DataFrame(x, columns= data.columns)
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X_df, y, test_size=0.20)

#Converting the data into proper LGB Dataset Format
d_train=lgb.Dataset(X_train, label=y_train)


#Declaring the parameters
params = {
    'task': 'train', 
    'boosting': 'gbdt',
    'objective': 'regression',
    'num_leaves': 10,
    'learning_rate': 0.01,
    'metric': {'l2','l1'},
    'verbose': -1
}

print("Train a LightGBM Regression model")
clf=lgb.train(params,d_train,1000)

#model prediction on X_test
print("Predict the test set")
y_pred=clf.predict(X_test)

#using RMSE error metric
mse =mean_squared_error(y_pred,y_test)
print("RMSE: ", mse**0.5)
mlflow.log_metric("RMSE", mse**0.5)
```

And then from a notebook file I use the following:

```
from azureml.core import Workspace
from azureml.core import Experiment

# connect to your workspace
ws = Workspace.from_config()

experiment_name = "get-started-with-jobsubmission-tutorial-andlightgbm"
exp = Experiment(workspace=ws, name=experiment_name)



from azureml.core.environment import Environment

# use a curated environment that has already been built for you

env = Environment.get(workspace=ws, 
                      name="AzureML-sklearn-1.0-ubuntu20.04-py38-cpu", 
                      version=1)

from azureml.core import ScriptRunConfig

args = ["--tablename", "BelgiumRealEstate"]

src = ScriptRunConfig(
    source_directory="",
    script="train.py",
    arguments=args,
    compute_target="local",
    environment=env,
)

run = exp.submit(config=src)
run.wait_for_completion(show_output=True)
```

As you can see in the train.py file I am logging the RMSE, however the metric does not appear on the metrics tab.

What should I do?

Answer (score 2):

In the mentioned code, **Run** library is not called and to display the log metrics, in metrics tab we need to use **get_context()** and run it with **Run** method as mentioned below.

```
from azureml.core import Run
run = Run.get_context()
run.log(' RMSE', mse**0.5)
mlflow.log_metric("RMSE", mse**0.5)
```

Comment: whats the difference with: mlflow.set_tracking_uri(ws.get_mlflow_tracking_uri()) ?  This line of code worked for me too.